# How to Express A Regex That Accepts Nothing

Tags: regex

I'm asked to write a regex that accepts the complement of another given regex:

```
(a*b*)*
```

This regex seems to accept every single string on the alphabet consisting of {a, b}, so I believe that its complement must accept no strings at all on this alphabet.

How can this be expressed as a regex? Is it possible?

Comment: The opposite would be: [^ab]+ it matches strings not starting with 'a' or 'b'.

Comment: I suppose I'm confused on how it doesn't pick up 'ba'.  Using the star closure, we can have 0 or more concatenations, correct?  So in the first round, we can concatenate 0 a's with 1 b to get b, then because we have a Kleene start at the end, we can go for another round and concatenate 1 a and 0 b's to the previous string and obtain 'ba'.  Am I confusing something?

Comment: I deleted that wrong comment, forget it.

Answer (score 0):

For the complement of `(a*b*)*`, the simplest answer seems to be `.*[^ab].*` (meaning: string containing a character that is neither `a` or `b`). It works whenever alphabet is just {a, b} or it has more characters.

To express a regex matching nothing in general, `$.` (meaning "string with a character after its end") is a good candidate. Or `.^`, which may be more performant in some implementations.

Comment: This will match: 'ab1ab'.

Comment: Yup, cause this string is in complement of `(a*b*)*`, that is what question was about. Clarified.

Comment: '(a\*b\*)*' will also match 'ab1ab' so it's not the opposite.

Comment: How would `(a*b*)*` match ab1ab? The only characters it can match are `a` and `b`. There is no way it could match the `1` in the middle.

Comment: Zero length matches! Try https://regexr.com/40pvh

Comment: Man, what are you talking about? This page shows that both `ab`s in `ab1ab` match the expression, but it also clearly shows that the `1` is not matched in any way, and the whole string doesn't match as well. And the comment about zero-length matches is completely irrelevant.